# Find the mistakes in a "proof" of the 4-colour Theorem

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, coloring, fake-proofs

I am working on the following exercise:

> Find all mistakes in the following “proof” of the Four Colour Theorem.
>
> Suppose, for contradiction, that the Four Colour Theorem is false. Let $v$ be a vertex
>   of degree $d := δ(G) \le 5$ in a smallest non-4-colourable planar graph $G$. Fix a drawing of $G$ and a 4-colouring $c$ of $G-v$. Denote the neighbours of $v$ by $x_1, \ldots , x_d$ in the order they lie around $v$ in the drawing. Furthermore, set $G_{i,j} := G[c^{−1}(i) \cup c^{−1}(j)]$. Since $G$ is not 4-colourable, we know that
>
> no 4-colouring of $G-v$ uses less than four colours for $N(v)$. (1)
>
> In particular, $d \ge 4$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $c(x_i) = i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$ and, if $d = 5$, then $c(x_5) \in {1, 2}$.
>
> Suppose first that $d = 4$. If there is no $x_1–x_3$ path in $G_{1,3}$, then we can recolour $x_1$ with colour $3$ by exchanging the colours in the component of $G_{1,3}$ that contains $x_1$ and obtain a colouring $c'$ that contradicts (1). Otherwise, $G_{2,4}$ contains no $x_2–x_4$ path and thus we can recolour $x_2$ with colour $4$, contradicting (1).
>
> Now suppose that $d = 5$ and $c(x_5) = 1$. If there is no $x_3–\{x_1, x_5\}$ path in $G_{1,3}$, we can recolour $x_3$ with colour $1$. Otherwise, we can recolour $x_2$ with colour $4$ as in the case $d = 4$. Either way, we construct a colouring of $G-v$ that contradicts (1).
>
> Finally, suppose that $d = 5$ and $c(x_5) = 2$. If there is no $x_1–x_3$ path in $G_{1,3}$ or no $x_1–x_4$ path in $G_{1,4}$, then we can recolour $x_1$ with colour $3$ or $4$, respectively, and get a contradiction to (1). Otherwise, there is neither an $x_2–x_4$ path in $G_{2,4}$ nor an $x_5–x_3$ path in $G_{2,3}$. Thus, we can recolour $x_2$ with colour $4$ and $x_5$ with colour $3$, again a contradiction to (1).

My commentary: We know that $G$ contains a vertex with degree $\le$ 5 since $G$ has to be planar by the 4 colour theorem.

Do you see any other errors?

Comment: Both statements you found actually look correct.

Comment: Are you sure that we can find a vertex of degree $\le 5$ in every graph?

Comment: @3nodatur Are you proving the 4-color theorem for every graph?

Comment: You are right, the 4 colour theorem requires a planar graph. I will edit

Comment: If $d=5$ then $x_5$ is adjacent to $x_1.$ Given that $c(x_1) = 1$ as assumed, we must have $c(x_5)\neq 1.$ Are you sure the "proof" claims that $c(x_5)\in\{1,2\}$ and not $c(x_5)\in\{2,3\}$?

Comment: @DavidK Yes the proof claims $c(x_5) \in \{1,2\}$

Comment: So we found a first error. But I got a question: Why should $x_5$ be adjacent to $x_1$ if $d=5$?

Comment: I had assumed $v$ was surrounded. On second thought, if the region represented by $v$ is (for example) the first quadrant and that $x_1$ is _not_ adjacent to $x_d.$ If that is the case, $c(x_5)$ could be anything other than $4.$ Of course, that's assuming that a minimal non-4-colorable graph would not just have a vertex of degree $5$ or less, but that it would have such a vertex that wasn't surrounded.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "surrounded" I do not get it

Comment: This is Kempe's flawed proof.  It seems to me to be correct except for the last paragraph.  The error is explained at https://msp.org/involve/2009/2-3/involve-v2-n3-p01-p.pdf page $251$.

Comment: I am curious about the other mistakes on this proof, did you find any of those? Or at least which parts of these proof are stated correctly?

Comment: I am curious about the other mistakes on this proof, did you find any of those? Or at least which parts of these proof are stated correctly?